# OpenCV get coordinates / radius in pixel

Tags: ios, opencv, image-processing, opencv3.0, opencv3.1

I have the code that applies some transformations for image for detecting circles

(`GaussianBlur->cvtColor(gray)->canny->HoughCircles`)

and as for result i got `vector<Vec3f> circles;` array.

If I draw the result with OpenCV:

```
cv::Point center(cvRound(circles[i][0]), cvRound(circles[i][1]));
int radius = cvRound(circles[i][2]);
    //circle center
circle( originalMat, center, 3, Scalar(0,255,0), -1, 8, 0 );
    // circle outline
circle( originalMat, center, radius, Scalar(0,0,255), 1, 8, 0 );
```

It looks ok(*see attached image, blue circle*)

But in case I'm trying to draw image not via OpenCV, I've got another circle (or ellipse sometimes)(*red circle on attached image*):

```
 UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(image.size); //the same size as original
 [image drawAtPoint:CGPointZero];
 CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
 [[UIColor redColor] setStroke];
 CGRect circleRect = CGRectMake(circles[i][0] - circles[i][2] ,
                                circles[i][1] - circles[i][2],
                                circles[i][0] + circles[i][2],
                                circles[i][1] + circles[i][2]
                               );
circleRect = CGRectInset(circleRect, 5, 5);
CGContextStrokeEllipseInRect(ctx, circleRect);
UIImage *retImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Why does it happen? How can I get coordinates and radius size in pixel to draw it correctly?

[image]

p.s: `UIImage` to `Mat` conversation i got form [documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/ios/image_manipulation/image_manipulation.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`CGRectMake` needs `(x, y, width, height)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/coregraphics/1455245-cgrectmake) and not the coordinates to *top-left* and *bottom-right* points. So you need to change to:

```
 CGRect circleRect = CGRectMake(circles[i][0] - circles[i][2] ,
                                circles[i][1] - circles[i][2],
                                2 * circles[i][2],
                                2 * circles[i][2]
                           );
```

Comment: yes, it helped, thank you. the circle center is ok, but radius a bit smaller (i've removed rounding) than original :(

Comment: It's a bit smaller because you used `CGRectInset`